# How to create a macro that suppresses errors and warnings?

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, julia

I'd like to redefine or overwrite some functions in `Base`, without the users noticing about this. I found this trick sometime ago:

```rb
original_stderr = STDERR
redirect_stderr()
# code
redirect_stderr(original_stderr)
```

This became a repetitive pattern for me, so I did a macro:

```rb
macro suppress_err(block)
    quote
        orig_err = STDERR
        redirect_stderr()
        val = $block
        redirect_stderr(orig_err)
        val
    end
end
```

But it has never behaved as expected (even without the macro):

- *jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: broken pipe EPIPE on windows()*

  - [KristofferC/PimpMyREPL.jl/#14](https://github.com/KristofferC/PimpMyREPL.jl/issues/14)
- *REPL: jl_uv_writecb() broken pipe EPIPE*

  - [JuliaLang/JuliaParser.jl/#63](https://github.com/JuliaLang/JuliaParser.jl/issues/63#issuecomment-242821101)

In Windows:

```rb
julia> @suppress_err warn()

julia> @suppress_err error()
ERROR:
 in error at error.jl:22
```

Windows Subsystem for Linux:

```rb
julia> @suppress_err warn()
[1]    17 abort (core dumped)  julia
julia  7.69s user 2.36s system 106% cpu 9.441 total
```

In Linux:

```rb
julia> @suppress_err +(x, y) = x - y                                                                                                                                                                                                      
ERROR: UndefVarError: #11#x not defined                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:234                                                                                                                                                                                                
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:92 [inlined]                                                                                                                                                                                             
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:46
```

Obviously I'm doing something terribly wrong, what's the correct way I should tackle this? Should I raise an issue at the Julia repository?

I have also tried using `close` on both `err_rd, err_wr = redirect_stderr()`, before redirecting again to the original `STDERR` without success.

### Update:

I have made a [Suppressor](https://github.com/Ismael-VC/Suppressor.jl) package with what I've done so you can easily test it:

```rb
Pkg.clone("https://github.com/Ismael-VC/Suppressor.jl")
```

All the macros have the same basic form:

```rb
macro suppress_err(block)
    quote
        let
            if ccall(:jl_generating_output, Cint, ()) == 0
                ORIGINAL_STDERR = STDERR
                err_rd, err_wr = redirect_stderr()

                value = $(esc(block))

                REDIRECTED_STDERR = STDERR
                redirect_stderr(ORIGINAL_STDERR)

                # This doesn't help:
                # close(err_rd)
                # close(err_wr)

                return value
            end
        end
    end
end
```

- I added the safety check from `JuliaParser` [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/JuliaParser.jl/blame/985c2b5e23af26b9a4f1c66b3da5ea96c90f4eb2/bin/repl.jl#L7-L10)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the return value of the original `redirect_stderr`. It returns both the read and the write end, but while the write end is stored in `STDERR`, the read end is not, so the GC may decide to get rid of it. If that happens, it gets closed at the system level, so when julia tries to write to it, it gets that error.

**Note**: example code below updated as per current [`Suppressor.jl`](https://git.io/vPCVy) version.

```rb
macro suppress_err(block)
    quote
        if ccall(:jl_generating_output, Cint, ()) == 0
            ORIGINAL_STDERR = STDERR
            err_rd, err_wr = redirect_stderr()
            err_reader = @async readstring(err_rd)

            value = $(esc(block))

            redirect_stderr(ORIGINAL_STDERR)
            close(err_wr)

            return value
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I have added the same test you used [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/JuliaParser.jl/blame/985c2b5e23af26b9a4f1c66b3da5ea96c90f4eb2/bin/repl.jl#L7-L10) at the JuliaParser REPL. Notice that issue [#63](https://github.com/JuliaLang/JuliaParser.jl/issues/63#issuecomment-242821101) of the JuliaParser REPL is referenced in the question (which is still an issue, I will update it shortly). So even with the new test I would expect it to fail, and even if it doesn't fail it miss behaves as noted in the question update. Could you please give me some example code?

Comment: What I mean is that you need to keep the return value live: `stream = redirect_stderr()` and make sure stream doesn't go out of scope while you're using it. Normally you'd read from it so that's how it doesn't go out of scope.

Comment: Thank you very much Keno, I finally understand. One odd thing is that while this fixes the PimpMyREPL issue, it doesn't fix the JuliaParser one AFAICT, so I'm not sold on this macro yet.