# Suppress deprecation warnings in Julia 0.6 without using `--depwarn=no` or a package

Tags: julia

I am writing a tool in Julia that requires a package with a deprecated function.

My script is called from the command line and takes many arguments so I would like to avoid using `--depwarn=no` to suppress deprecation warnings.

Instead, I'd like to embed this `--depwarn=no` or somehow signal this into my script so the user doesn't have to type it in, or worry about it whenever they run the script.

Does anyone know how can I do this using only `Base` Julia without installing any another package like [Suppressor.jl](https://github.com/SalchiPapa/Suppressor.jl)?

Comment: This is one question and it's pretty direct. I don't know why a bunch of people who aren't part of the Julia community would put this on hold, but that's very rude for no reason.

Comment: feel free to join [the Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia) or [the Julia Slack](https://slackinvite.julialang.org/) to ask this question and get more answers.  I'm sorry this happened to you.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas when this happens, we can just edit the question to improve a little (formatting for example) and then (if one has enough reputation) vote to **reopen**. As to why this was put on hold, maybe it was just to farm SO badges?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks for inviting me to the Julia Slack, I've requested to join. The Gitter channel looks really useful too, I'm happy to see there are  active support channels I can participate in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote Suppressor initially, as far as I know there is no other way right now, [which is why I started Suppressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170298/how-to-create-a-macro-that-suppresses-errors-and-warnings).

You could always copy paste verbatim the `suppress*` macro you need, into your code (but I would advise just to use Suppressor honestly, in case of updates), all the Suppressor macros are self contained and require only `Base` (if you are on 0.6.x this macros shouldn't need `Compat`).

- [`@suppress_err`](https://github.com/SalchiPapa/Suppressor.jl/blob/74dfed0581330e4f435d69a4d6c059ef0b6f5ae8/src/Suppressor.jl#L63-L84) (latest version):

```rb
"""
    @suppress_err expr

Suppress the STDERR stream for the given expression.
"""
macro suppress_err(block)
    quote
        if ccall(:jl_generating_output, Cint, ()) == 0
            ORIGINAL_STDERR = STDERR
            err_rd, err_wr = redirect_stderr()
            err_reader = @async read(err_rd, String)
        end

        value = $(esc(block))

        if ccall(:jl_generating_output, Cint, ()) == 0
            redirect_stderr(ORIGINAL_STDERR)
            close(err_wr)
        end

        value
    end
end
```

If you just want to get rid of the deprecation warnings, then `@suppress_err` is all you need. There have been improvements recently on the current Julia master branch related to logging, but I haven't checked out those yet.